# Redirect user if not logged in react js jwt node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

There are already many answers but I couldn't use them according to my scenario
in which my login component is a child component and i am using react-router-dom of 5.1.2 version
currently i am using local storage to save authToken but I know it is not a good approach. Where should I save the auth token then such that whenever someone tries to hit login route manually or by button they are redirected because token was expired
my route that i am currently using in app.js

```
 <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/login-register"} component={(!isVerified)?LoginRegister:HomeFashion}/>
```

and this is the child component login

```
const login = async()=>{
try{
  const options = {
username:username,
password:password

  }
var response = await axios.post(CONFIG.url+'api/login',options)
localStorage.setItem("__user",JSON.stringify(response.data))

history.push({
  pathname: '/',
  // search: '?update=true',  // query string
  state: {  // location state
    user: response.data, 
    
  },
});

}catch(err){
  isError(true)
}
}

React.useEffect(()=>{

  if(location.state!==undefined){
   setMsg(location.state.msg)
if(msg)
 {
   alert(msg)
 }
}

  },[location])
```

what i am doing is when i am successfully logged in i get token and user data in response form backend I store it in localStorage and redirects things according to it

what is the right way to do so?

Comment: I found usefull this guide: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/06/react-jwt-authentication-tutorial-example

Comment: You can do it without redirect, just use `useContext()` example https://dev.to/dancurtis/learn-to-usecontext-with-hooks-in-3-minutes-4c4g

Comment: Hi vitality, i followed that tutorial and i understand it. but what is I have to use browserrouter then i can use user provider too
or can i use both of them i am talking about this part
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
===== i need to use navigate to other components
  <UserProvider>
    <App />
    </UserProvider>,

===== in tutorial